# JTable row Color need to be change in Java

Tags: java

i am beginner of java swing application.i need to change to jtable row color based on role.This Employee registration form consist of different roles like sales man,sales manager,software enginner,project manager etc. the jtable row color will be changed based on the role of the employee.

```
 List<Color> rowColours = Arrays.asList(
                Color.RED,
                Color.GREEN,
                Color.CYAN
            );

            public void setRowColour(int row, Color c) {
                rowColours.set(row, c);
                fireTableRowsUpdated(row, row);
            }

            public Color getRowColour(int row) {
                return rowColours.get(row);
            }

            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return 3;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
                return String.format("%d %d", row, column);
            }
    
     public void table()
     {
        
         int a;
         try {
            pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from  registation");
            rs = pst.executeQuery();
            
            rd = rs.getMetaData();
            a = rd.getColumnCount();
            model = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            model.setRowCount(0);
             model.setRowColour(1, Color.YELLOW);
            
            while(rs.next())
            {
                Vector v = new Vector();
                
                for(int i=1; i<=a; i++)
                {
                    v.add(rs.getString("id"));
                    v.add(rs.getString("name"));
                    v.add(rs.getString("mobile"));
                    v.add(rs.getString("role"));
                }
                
                model.addRow(v);
                
            }

            
        } catch (SQLException e) 
         {  
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
     }
```

above code i tried. but  **model.setRowColour(1, Color.YELLOW);** this line i got the error
**The method setRowColour(int, Color) is undefined for the type DefaultTableModel**

Comment: The Oracle tutorial, [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), will help you.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay close attention to the [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) sections.

Comment: Check out [Table Row Rendering](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/table-row-rendering/) which shows how to color a row based on data in the row.